# JSoup: Retrieve element that does not contain a specific attribute

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a table that contain follow logic.

1. The table display list of names
2. For every row that contain `<tr class=hiderow><td class=packagename>...</td></tr>` -> this row will not be visible.

So the table might contain 100 rows, but if there are 20 rows contain `class=hiderow`, then the user can only see 80 rows on the page. I want to retrieve the name of those 80 rows (not 100). So I need to parse out data that does not contain `class=hiderow`. I know how to obtain every name using `jsoup`, I also see there is in the documentation 
`:not(selector) elements that do not match the selector.` but i am not sure how to use it. Please help.

**EDIT** I have figure out how to do it. Please let me know if there is better way.
**EDIT2** Please use solution below from BalusC. It's much cleaner.

```
public void obtainPackageName(String urlLink) throws IOException{
    List<String> pdfList = new ArrayList<String>();
    URL url = new URL(urlLink);
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);
    Element table = doc.select("table[id=mastertableid]").first();
    Iterator<Element> rowIter = table.select("tr").iterator();
    while(rowIter.hasNext()){
        Element row = rowIter.next();
        if(!row.className().contains("hiderow")){
            Element packageName = row.select("td[class=packagename]").first();
            if(packageName != null){
                pdfList.add(packageName.text());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to apply the `:not()` on the element of interest (which is `tr` in your case) and then pass the element-relative CSS selector into it on which the element should **not** match (which is `.hiderow` in your case).

So, this should do:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(urlLink).get();
Elements packagenames = document.select("#mastertableid tr:not(.hiderow) td.packagename");
List<String> pdfList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Element packagename : packagenames) {
    pdfList.add(packagename.text()); 
}
```

Comment: this look much cleaner, I will try this. TY BalusC